# How to make geoJson files and visualise them

Tags: json, geojson, kepler

How can I create geoJson files on Mac? I tried `touch new.geojson` after which I copied the data into the file but I don't think it gives me the correct file type since I am not able to load the file on **Kepler.gl**

I tried to upload this data but it never loads on Kepler. If I try some random example from the internet, it loads immediately even though the format seems to be the same.

```
"{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-0.796272,5.225736],[-0.795293,5.228452],[-0.806762,5.222764],[-0.818826,5.23953],[-0.829519,5.260144],[-0.860461,5.273933],[-0.890056,5.309425],[-0.875031,5.326234],[-0.843153,5.323144],[-0.801128,5.339694],[-0.759914,5.337996],[-0.642737,5.383214],[-0.642423,5.383474],[-0.575465,5.454165],[-0.558689,5.486223],[-0.514209,5.512632],[-0.364606,5.552434],[-0.343397,5.546054],[-0.309366,5.553826],[-0.285525,5.569787],[-0.28366,5.57064],[-0.257415,5.603225],[-0.156054,5.629528],[-0.015683,5.684939],[-0.014548,5.685099],[0.054634,5.763615],[0.289173,5.86565],[0.521139,5.896969],[0.530532,6.004213],[0.555024,6.007513],[0.574476,5.990664],[0.595112,5.998843],[0.595206,5.998879],[0.664647,6.019722],[0.665004,6.019413],[0.675656,5.984694],[0.66338,5.964361],[0.690962,5.941331],[0.719717,5.890157],[0.781744,5.843708],[0.830645,5.778435],[0.919066,5.801578],[0.925173,5.788085]]}"
```

which I think should be turned into this before trying to visualise:

```
{type:"LineString",coordinates:[[-0.796272,5.225736],[-0.795293,5.228452],[-0.806762,5.222764],[-0.818826,5.23953],[-0.829519,5.260144],[-0.860461,5.273933],[-0.890056,5.309425],[-0.875031,5.326234],[-0.843153,5.323144],[-0.801128,5.339694],[-0.759914,5.337996],[-0.642737,5.383214],[-0.642423,5.383474],[-0.575465,5.454165],[-0.558689,5.486223],[-0.514209,5.512632],[-0.364606,5.552434],[-0.343397,5.546054],[-0.309366,5.553826],[-0.285525,5.569787],[-0.28366,5.57064],[-0.257415,5.603225],[-0.156054,5.629528],[-0.015683,5.684939],[-0.014548,5.685099],[0.054634,5.763615],[0.289173,5.86565],[0.521139,5.896969],[0.530532,6.004213],[0.555024,6.007513],[0.574476,5.990664],[0.595112,5.998843],[0.595206,5.998879],[0.664647,6.019722],[0.665004,6.019413],[0.675656,5.984694],[0.66338,5.964361],[0.690962,5.941331],[0.719717,5.890157],[0.781744,5.843708],[0.830645,5.778435],[0.919066,5.801578],[0.925173,5.788085]]}
```

But both of them don't really work when I try to upload them to kepler. How else can I create geoJson files?

I also tried copying the first format here:
https://geoman.io/geojson-editor

After which I downloaded the geoJSON file and tried to load it into Kepler. Nothing happens even though the uploading window closes.

**Edit:**

I tried to do this on TurfJs on JsFiddle:

```
var stringnew = turf.lineString([-0.796272,5.225736],[-0.795293,5.228452],[-0.806762,5.222764],[-0.818826,5.23953],[-0.829519,5.260144],[-0.860461,5.273933],[-0.890056,5.309425],[-0.875031,5.326234],[-0.843153,5.323144],[-0.801128,5.339694],[-0.759914,5.337996],[-0.642737,5.383214],[-0.642423,5.383474],[-0.575465,5.454165],[-0.558689,5.486223],[-0.514209,5.512632],[-0.364606,5.552434],[-0.343397,5.546054],[-0.309366,5.553826],[-0.285525,5.569787],[-0.28366,5.57064],[-0.257415,5.603225],[-0.156054,5.629528],[-0.015683,5.684939],[-0.014548,5.685099],[0.054634,5.763615],[0.289173,5.86565],[0.521139,5.896969],[0.530532,6.004213],[0.555024,6.007513],[0.574476,5.990664],[0.595112,5.998843],[0.595206,5.998879],[0.664647,6.019722],[0.665004,6.019413],[0.675656,5.984694],[0.66338,5.964361],[0.690962,5.941331],[0.719717,5.890157],[0.781744,5.843708],[0.830645,5.778435],[0.919066,5.801578],[0.925173,5.788085])

console.log(stringnew);
console.log('hi');
```

But I never see any output on the console. How else can I make the conversion?

http://jsfiddle.net/ed8hx01c/1/

If I run this example, I do see an output on the console:

http://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/o1wysgtj/

Comment: "I tried touch new.geojson but I don't think it gives me the correct results" That's creating an empty file named `new.geojson`, so it's normal it won't be of use...

Comment: On the second one it's not valid since it `coordinates` needs to be between quotes...

Comment: Of course I added content to it afterwards. But it never loads onto Kepler @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid geojson `LineString` would look like this:

```
{
   "type":"Feature",
   "properties":{

   },
   "geometry":{
      "type":"LineString",
      "coordinates": [[-0.796272,5.225736],[-0.795293,5.228452],[-0.806762,5.222764],[-0.818826,5.23953],[-0.829519,5.260144],[-0.860461,5.273933],[-0.890056,5.309425],[-0.875031,5.326234],[-0.843153,5.323144],[-0.801128,5.339694],[-0.759914,5.337996],[-0.642737,5.383214],[-0.642423,5.383474],[-0.575465,5.454165],[-0.558689,5.486223],[-0.514209,5.512632],[-0.364606,5.552434],[-0.343397,5.546054],[-0.309366,5.553826],[-0.285525,5.569787],[-0.28366,5.57064],[-0.257415,5.603225],[-0.156054,5.629528],[-0.015683,5.684939],[-0.014548,5.685099],[0.054634,5.763615],[0.289173,5.86565],[0.521139,5.896969],[0.530532,6.004213],[0.555024,6.007513],[0.574476,5.990664],[0.595112,5.998843],[0.595206,5.998879],[0.664647,6.019722],[0.665004,6.019413],[0.675656,5.984694],[0.66338,5.964361],[0.690962,5.941331],[0.719717,5.890157],[0.781744,5.843708],[0.830645,5.778435],[0.919066,5.801578],[0.925173,5.788085]]
   }
}
```

(generated using [TurfJS](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineString))

Download it and have fun visualizing!

[image]

---

EDIT: how to use turf.js

1. go to turfjs.org & open up the dev tools console
2. paste in the following:

```
const pseudo_line_string = {type:"LineString",coordinates:[[-0.796272,5.225736],[-0.795293,5.228452],[-0.806762,5.222764],[-0.818826,5.23953],[-0.829519,5.260144],[-0.860461,5.273933],[-0.890056,5.309425],[-0.875031,5.326234],[-0.843153,5.323144],[-0.801128,5.339694],[-0.759914,5.337996],[-0.642737,5.383214],[-0.642423,5.383474],[-0.575465,5.454165],[-0.558689,5.486223],[-0.514209,5.512632],[-0.364606,5.552434],[-0.343397,5.546054],[-0.309366,5.553826],[-0.285525,5.569787],[-0.28366,5.57064],[-0.257415,5.603225],[-0.156054,5.629528],[-0.015683,5.684939],[-0.014548,5.685099],[0.054634,5.763615],[0.289173,5.86565],[0.521139,5.896969],[0.530532,6.004213],[0.555024,6.007513],[0.574476,5.990664],[0.595112,5.998843],[0.595206,5.998879],[0.664647,6.019722],[0.665004,6.019413],[0.675656,5.984694],[0.66338,5.964361],[0.690962,5.941331],[0.719717,5.890157],[0.781744,5.843708],[0.830645,5.778435],[0.919066,5.801578],[0.925173,5.788085]]}
```

```
const line_string = turf.lineString(pseudo_line_string.coordinates);
```

```
JSON.stringify(line_string);
copy(line_string)
```

3. that's it.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding how to use TurfJs. Could you please see the update in the qs?

Comment: Apart from that, if I manually add the type and properties, I'm able to load the visualization.

Comment: Cool. Updated my answer w/ a turf intro. Good luck.

Comment: As to your JSFiddle -- you didn't correctly paste the coordinates & were missing the outer array `[  ... ]`